# Counter part of AngularJS attribute directives in React

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

**What's the best way to implement something like AngularJS's attribute directive in React?**

I have been using React for more than 6 months now.

I understand, AngularJS works on DOM and React works on Virtual DOM but say I want to implement something like `ng-if` in React instead of writing ternary operator everywhere. I know I can write a wrapper element component like

```
<ShowIf condition={this.state.something}>
    <div>
        Some text
    </div>
</ShowIf>
```

But what I am looking for is something like this

```
<div doThisIf={this.state.something}>
    Some text
</div>
```

I have come across [React templates](http://wix.github.io/react-templates/) by Wix.com, but it is a transpiler. I am looking for a generic solution.

This may be against the practice of React but it really makes things very easier. Any suggestions?

Comment: Since a `<div>` is not a react component, you won't be able to directly add properties like that. Why is the the `<ShowIf>` not satisfactory? Doesn't seem like it gets you much doing it the second way.

Comment: `<div>` is a React component which translates to `React.DOM.div`. `<ShowIf>` isn't satisfactory because, say, if I want to add a new event on <div> like `onHover` which takes two functions, I can't do it just like `onClick`, I will need to write a wrapper component `onHover` but it makes more sense to be like a property on `<div>`.

Comment: I've posted an answer that solves it the way I solve this myself (and that seems to be common in the React community)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to make components to do this, add a conditional before your `render` method's `return` statement like so:

```
React.createClass({

  //... some other stuff

  render: function () {
    var something;
    if (this.state.something) {
      something = (
        <span onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Some React stuff here...
        </span>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Something</h1>
        <p>Any other stuff here...</p>
        {/* This only shows up if `this.state.something` is true: */}
        {something}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

If a variable returns `null`/`undefined` it will not render and no HTML will be created for it.